# iOS - shortcut to synthesize properties using extension

Tags: ios, properties, ios-extensions

Let's say i have a class definition header file like this :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) SomeObject *managedObject;

@end
```

instead of defining the @synthesize  on managedObject to create the getters/setters a friend of mine told me i can do the following header definition using a class extension to do the synthesis more cleanly:

```
#import "TSPAppDelegate.h"

@interface TSPAppDelegate () //notice the class extension here

@property (strong, nonatomic) SomeObject *managedObject; //this will already be synthesized since its an extension


@end
```

Could some one explain how this works using the extensions ?

Comment: You don't need to use @synthesize any more, it's done for you automatically. There's no difference between putting a property in the .h vs. an extension as far as synthesis of the properties goes.

Comment: As noted, `@synthesize` is no longer necessary. What differs in putting the `@property` is the scope of the property: putting it in the class interface header makes it visible to every class importing this header file (like the `public` keyword in Java), while putting it in the class extension makes it visible only to that file (usually the `.m` file).

Answer (score -2):

I think your friend is incorrect.  You have to @synthesize to have the getters/setters implemented for you

Comment: Getters and setters are created automatically for you , there's no need to use @synthesize any more unless you're overriding both the setter and getter (or getter only for a read-only property).